# ODBC link check failed error while compiling Erlang OTP on FreeBSD 10.1

Tags: erlang, freebsd

I am trying to compile Erlang OTP-R16B03-1 on FreeBSD 10.1 OS. When i run the `./configure` command the output is

```
odbc           : ODBC library - header check failed
```

I have tried installing unixODBC, iODBC. Also `/usr/ports/databases/unixODBC` exists. The `sql.h` file is located in `/usr/local/include`.

I am still getting the link failed error. Any help will be useful

The log for `./configure |grep odbc` command is as shown below

```
config.status: WARNING:  'Makefile.in' seems to ignore the --datarootdir setting
=== configuring in odbc/. (/root/otp_src_R16B03-1/lib/odbc/.)
checking for odbc in standard locations... -L/usr/local/lib
checking for SQLAllocHandle in -lodbc... no
configure: WARNING: "ODBC library - header check failed"
configure: WARNING: Check for large file support flags failed; getconf failed
odbc           : ODBC library - header check failed
```

Comment: Check `lib/odbc/config.log` for more detailed error messages. Also, [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19149714/113848) might help.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem on `erlang 21` but when I downloaded the newest version from github (`erlang 22`), and tried `./configure` the error `ODBC library - header check failed` appeared again but after trying `make install` again, everything finished successfully.

Answer (score 1):

What finally worked for me was

```
apt-get install unixodbc-dev
```

Then

```
 otp_build configure --with-odbc=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/
```